# jQuery change image while function is executing to show progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, asynchronous

I know that in some browsers (IE, Chrome) that changes to the DOM won't take place until after a function is completed.  I have read through various suggestions on how to deal with this, but I'm not having any luck.  I'm trying to loop through a series of AJAX calls and show progress for each line that is being processed.  The code is like this:

```
for(i=0; i < rowIds.length; i++){ 

  $(rowImage).attr('src', '/images/spinner.gif');

       $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: ajaxUrl,
                    async: false,
                    processData: true,
                    data: {},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $(rowImage).attr('src', '/images/success.gif');
                   }
              });
}
```

I've read several suggestions about trying to insure that the image transformation takes place before proceeding, such as doing this before the AJAX call starts:

```
var changeImage = function() {
    $(rowImage).attr('src', '/images/spinner.gif');
};

$.when(changeImage() ).done( function() {
           //run AJAX call
```

But that doesn't make a difference.  The images don't change until after the function is finished executing.

You will note that I have async set to false, and I'm doing that for various reasons.  But even without that in place, the issue persists.  I've also tried using setTimeOut() as has been suggested, and that doesn't seem to work  (And I know that setTimeOut() is meant for async mode, but even in async it doesn't seem to help.)

Comment: Welcome to the world of using Synchronous Ajax calls which lock up the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: ajaxUrl,
      async: false,
      processData: true,
      data: {},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
             $(rowImage).attr('src', '/images/success.gif');
      }
 });

 $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $(rowImage).attr('src', '/images/spinner.gif');
    }).ajaxStop(function () {

 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the two suggestions.  Unfortunately, neither seems to work.  .ajaxStart only fires at the first ajax call, but regardless the image does not change prior to the end.  I found out that .ajaxSend is best when trying to do something at the beginning of each ajax request in a sequence.  But while .ajaxSend does seem to work with any other code actions, it doesn't change any image until the end of all calls.  Same behavior with beforeSend. (This is true in both IE and Chrome, FF works fine even with my original code)